# Bootstrap form not showing cursor

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have a single page with bootstrap and a form, but the form is like disabled, it doesn't show the cursors to type inside.
I have reviewed the css to see if there was any wrong class but everything seems ok.

Heres my html

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contactForm.php" class="contact-form form" role="form">
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Your firstname *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your firstname" required="required" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Your email *</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your  email" required="required" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Your message for us *</label>
            <textarea rows="4" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" required="required" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <input type="submit" value="Send message" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the following scripts

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xyroL86j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an element laying over the top of your form and links. Use your browser's document inspector to find it. Look for forced heights, absolute positioning, and negative margins.

Comment: YES ! afer checking again the code, I found that I had an element over with 100% height that was causing that effect with the links and with the entire page ( wasnt able to select any text for example ). Thanks !